# Pandas ffill and bfill in the same column - conditional

Tags: pandas, ffill

I have a column with chemistries and at some point I have the change of them. I want to ffill until the "changepoint" and bfill after it.

I have several change points like this:

```
date0   NaN
date1   chem1
date2   NaN
date3   NaN
date4   change
date5   NaN
date6   chem2
date7   chem2
date8   NaN
date9   change
date10   NaN
date11   chem3
date12   NaN
```

I would like to have it:

```
date0   chem1
date1   chem1
date2   chem1
date3   chem1
date4   change
date5   chem2
date6   chem2
date7   chem2
date8   chem2
date9   change
date10   chem3
date11   chem3
date12   chem3
```

any suggestions on the best approach here?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 'col' your second column, use a custom group:

```
df['col'] = df.groupby(df['col'].eq('change').cumsum())['col'].apply(lambda s:s.bfill().ffill())
```

Output;

```
      date     col
0    date0   chem1
1    date1   chem1
2    date2   chem1
3    date3   chem1
4    date4  change
5    date5   chem2
6    date6   chem2
7    date7   chem2
8    date8   chem2
9    date9  change
10  date10   chem3
11  date11   chem3
12  date12   chem3
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
df = pd.read_clipboard(header = None, names = ['a', 'b'])
```

Run an `ffill` on the second column (I relabelled the columns as `a` and `b`):

```py
step1 = df.b.ffill()
```

Run a condition on step1, and do a bfill after:

```py
step1 = step1.mask(step1.eq('change') & df.b.isna()).bfill()
df.assign(b = step1)

         a       b
0    date0   chem1
1    date1   chem1
2    date2   chem1
3    date3   chem1
4    date4  change
5    date5   chem2
6    date6   chem2
7    date7   chem2
8    date8   chem2
9    date9  change
10  date10   chem3
11  date11   chem3
12  date12   chem3
```